# Should I need to use same configration all hosts for Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, ambari, bigdata

I want to create multi hosts cluster for Hadoop. I want to install Apache Ambari on server with multi hosts but I have one confusion regarding hosts. Should I need to use same configuration on all hosts like (RAM, Processor, Hard Disk). I have one hosts have 64 GB ram and other two have 4GB RAM. Can I move with configuration or anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds like a perfect use case for [host config groups](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.5.0.3/bk_ambari-operations/content/using_host_config_groups.html) in Ambari. Just create 2 host groups with different memory settings

It's a usual practice to have few more powerful nodes for Ambari Server, master nodes like Namenode, Hbase Master, DB, and hundreds of less powerful slave nodes

Comment: Ok Means I am using with above configuration with master node more power ful and slave server with less powerful then it is ok right !!!. Please confirm it.